# Unabled to run an old Java binary in a Linux 64bits

Tags: java, linux, debian, 32bit-64bit

I've fallen (kind of) once again in an issue that I already solved months ago. I need to run a Java virtual POS that, according to the official manual, needs the Java VM 1.4.2, but the environment is Debian GNU/Linux 7 "Wheezy" amd64, and I haven't found that expecific version for that architecture (nor Solaris amd64 or IA64 fit to my case). That Virtual POS has been working perfectly fine, but in Debian GNU/Linux 6 "Squeeze" i686 (in other words, in a 32bits architecture). I've been trying to use the Oracle JDK 8 64bits. I've run execstack over libOasisEMSec.so, which I downloaded once again, but in 64 bits, from this site http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27875140/dir/opensuse_13.x/com/compat-32bit-2010.1.31-19.1.2.x86_64.rpm.html. The compilation is fine, but the execution gives me the following error:

```
# java -Djava.library.path=/var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux -classpath /var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux:/var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux exampledigest

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux/libOasisEMSec.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux/libOasisEMSec.so: /var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux/libOasisEMSec.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at OasisEMSecImp.<clinit>(OasisEMSecImp.java:9)
        at exampledigest.main(exampledigest.java:36)
```

The big question here is: how can I run this old Java binary, in a Debian Linux 64bits environment?

Comment: Can you try running... `java -d32 -Djava.library.path=/var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux -classpath /var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux:/var/www/vhosts/myvirtualshop.com/lib/Digest/linux examplediges`

Comment: Amazon has a 32 bit Debian squeeze AMI (ami-1212ef7b) and you can still get Java 1.4.x from Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html).  Not the prettiest solution but it might keep you moving forward.

Comment: @vidit: this is the JRE 1.8.0_77 64bits answer: "Error: This Java instance does not support a 32-bit JVM.
Please install the desired version."

Comment: @stdunbar: I already tried that, it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run 32 bit programms on 64 bit system you need to enable [Multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch):

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs -y
```

See example [32bit firefox/thunderbird on debian amd64](http://gromgull.net/blog/2013/02/32bit-firefoxthunderbird-on-debian-amd64/#post-628)

## If you need an older version of Sun Java

You need to download it from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html, unpack it yourself, and update your `$PATH` to point to it.  Possibly also your `$JAVA_HOME` for some tooling.

[The oficial Installation Notes for Linux](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-140719.html)

1. Make sure that execute permissions are set Run this command:

   ```
   chmod    +x j2re-1_4_2_<version>-linux-i586.bin
   ```
2. Run the self-extracting binary.

   Execute the downloaded file, prepended by the path to it. For
   example, if the file is in the current directory, prepend it with "
   ./" (necessary if " ." is not in the PATH environment variable):

   ```
   ./j2re-1_4_2_<version>-linux-i586.bin
   ```

> Note about System Preferences: By default, the installation script
> configures the system such that the backing store for system
> preferences is created inside the Java 2 Runtime Environment's
> installation directory. If the J2RE is installed on a network-mounted
> drive, it and the system preferences can be exported for sharing with
> Java runtime environments on other machines. As an alternative, root
> users can use the -localinstall option when running the installation
> script, as in this example:
>
> j2re-1_4_2_-linux-i586.bin -localinstall This option causes
> the system preferences to be stored in the /etc directory from which
> they can be shared only by VMs running on the local machine. You must
> be root user for the -localinstall option to work.

Comment: So, what you're telling me is that I can use a Java VM 32 bits in a Linux 64 bits environment, because that's exactly what I did in first place and it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You need enable multiarch support https://www.howtoforge.com/multiarch-how-to-use-32bit-packages-on-a-64bit-system-debian-7-wheezy